# Axios get url + state return undefined state even if the state exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I do an axios get(url + this.state.user) but the parameter is undefined for no reason because when i do a console log of the parameter it exists...

My code

```
    state = {
        user: [],
        taches : [],
        loading: false
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.setState({loading:true})
        axios.get('/get-user').then(response => {
                this.setState({user : response.data});
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
        axios.get('/get-taches/' + this.state.user.ID_Users).then(response => {
            console.log(this.state.user.ID_Users);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(this.state.user.ID_Users);
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

The parameter of axios get-taches return undefined but when i do a console log of it in the catch error it is defined and it shows in the console... I dont know where the problem is.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `axios.get` is async. Eventhough you have a `.then()` for them, your second request will be started way before the first request is finished. Furthermore, also `setState` is asynchronous, and you don't await it ...

Comment: Setting state is also asynchronous. Use `componentDidUpdate`. Or use `response.data.ID_Users` for the 2nd request by moving it inside the first requests callback. Also, if `user` is an object, you should initialize it with `{}` not `[]`.

Comment: both axios calls are async, if get-teaches is dependant on getuser, you should be able to put inside the the first then call
```axios.get('/get-user').then(response => {
                this.setState({user : response.data});
                axios.get('/get-taches/' + response.data.ID_Users)...
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })```

Comment: Thank you guys i put my second  axios request in the first one and it worked great ! Thank you mates !